# Using conditional in azurerm_sql_failover_group causes error with partner blocks

Tags: azure, terraform

I am using a resource from the AzureRM provider.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/sql_failover_group

I get the below error when trying to conditionally create this resource depending on a json value from a file.

Hoping for some ideas on how to tackle this, would creating a sub module to call help? I believe the problem is that terraform expands the whole block and checks against defined schema.

With the below code

```
resource "azurerm_sql_failover_group" "failover_group" {
  for_each = try(local.ctx.Pod.disable_secondary_region == true, false) ? {} : local.pod_locations.primary

  name                = "${var.prefix}-failover-group"
  resource_group_name = var.regional_data_rg[each.value].name
  server_name         = azurerm_sql_server.instance[each.value].name
  databases           = local.primary_dbs_ids

  dynamic "partner_servers" {
    for_each = try(local.ctx.Pod.disable_secondary_region == true, false) ? [] : nonsensitive(local.secondary_servers)
    content {
      id = partner_servers.value.id
    }
  }

  read_write_endpoint_failover_policy {
    mode          = "Automatic"
    grace_minutes = 60
  }

  depends_on = [azurerm_sql_database.database_secondary]
}
```

**Error:**
*error: Insufficient partner_servers blocks
2022-04-06T00:38:06.5068399Z
2022-04-06T00:38:06.5068981Z   on .terraform\modules\data.data\pipeline\data\sql\main.tf line 288, in resource "azurerm_sql_failover_group" "failover_group":
2022-04-06T00:38:06.5069637Z  288: resource "azurerm_sql_failover_group" "failover_group" {
2022-04-06T00:38:06.5069842Z
2022-04-06T00:38:06.5070280Z At least 1 "partner_servers" blocks are required.*

Comment: "depending on a json value from a file" - what file, which value? Your question does not show any json file, how it relates to your code.

Comment: We load the local.ctx object like below from a json file. The issue is even if I remove references to it and just use count = 0 when defining the failover group I still get this error
`locals {
  pod_locations = data.terraform_remote_state.pod_bootstrap.outputs.pod_locations
  ctx           = jsondecode(file("${path.root}/../../metadata.g.json"))
}`